# trait PlainResult in package mvc is deprecated: In Play 2.3, SimpleResult will be the only type of result

Tags: java, scala, playframework, deprecated, playframework-2.2

i am using scala  with play framework 2.2, i am using below piece of code for getting that user is in session or not.

```
session.get("userId").map { user =>
//-----------------      
}.getOrElse {
//----------------      
}
```

but from some days it getting warning when i am compilling my project.

```
 trait PlainResult in package mvc is deprecated: In Play 2.3, SimpleResult will be the only 

type of result
[warn]        session.get("userId").map { user =>
[warn]                              ^
```

so as it is now deprecated , so what i use now for getting that user is in the session or not without any warning?

Comment: The message complains about the result of type `PlainResult` (what is the content of your map function ?) not the way you use the session...

Comment: http://www.mariussoutier.com/blog/2013/09/17/playframework-2-2-action-building-action-composition/

Comment: To help you with this you need to provide the code you use inside the call of map. That is where thy type comes from.

Answer (score 4):

The problem has nothing to do with the piece of code you provided.

Play 2.1 provided 3 types of synchronous results: `Result, SimpleResult and PlainResult`
In Play 2.2, there is only: `SimpleResult`, which will be renamed to `Result` in Play 2.3.

Inside your map function, you have a piece of code that is returning `PlainResult`.

If you are just using standard Play api functions, you don't need to worry about, since there is a work in progress and some of this warning will go away. If you build something more complex of top of that, you may want to take a look and fix the function you built to return SimpleResult. It is really hard for me to say without seeing the code inside the map function.

Anyway, if you want to be sure, you may want to switch to playframework current snapshot and see how if it works.

For the sample code:

```
def ok() = Ok.withSession(
  "xxx" -> "yyy"
).withLang(Lang("en-US"))
```

For Play 2.2.0, I get:

```
 trait PlainResult in package mvc is deprecated: In Play 2.3, SimpleResult will be the only type of result
[warn]   def ok() = Ok.withSession(
```

If I change it to Play 2.3-SNAPSHOT, I get no error at all, because withLang in Play 2.3 no longer returns PlainResult.

Answer (score 0):

```
def ok(): SimpleResult = Ok.withSession(
  "xxx" -> "yyy"
).withLang(Lang("en-US"))
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/AgDqci_fogY